# ASP VB .NET Passing Parameter to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ping

I am currently writing a ping status monitoring ASP. But i could not figure out how to pass data from calling a action to controller.

My Action Code as follow:-

```
Function showPing2(ByVal ipaddress As String) As String
    If ipaddress = 1 Then
        Return "Online"
    Else
        Return "Offline"
    End If
End Function
```

Calling method from Index.vbhtml

```
        @Html.Action("showPing2(1)")
```

I could not pass the value like that, it keep showing the error "HttpException was unhandled by user code"

Could anyone please tell me how to correctly pass value in ASP .NET?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax, try this:

```
@Html.Action("showPing2", new { ipaddress = "1" })
```

OR

```
@Html.Action("showPing2", "ControllerName", new { ipaddress = "1" })
```

**Added**

This is `C#` syntax as I understand from [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3amsXFFx4438YJ%3amsdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=by) or [Anonymous class initialization in VB.Net](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3acLCfrIui6KYJ%3astackoverflow.com/questions/849836/anonymous-class-initialization-in-vb-net%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=by), VB.NET is something like:

```
@Html.Action("showPing2", New With { .ipaddress = "1" })
```

Comment: i tried the @Html.Action("showPing2", new { ipaddress = "1" }) but it show Type or 'With' expected. Any idea? Thanks for help!

Comment: Okies, i use this syntax work "@Html.Action("showPing2", New With { .ipaddress = "1" })" .. Thank you so much!!!